# How to rewrite the torch.nn.LayerNorm function?

Tags: pytorch, normalization

I need to rewrite the layer normalization with torch without parameters to adjust different data size.

I have checked the API document of nn.LayerNorm

[image: 1]

and made some implementations with torch and numpy. In my test results, there is a few difference with torch and totally equal with numpy. Comparing with nn.LayerNorm with elementwise_affine =True, the torch implementation doesn't perform so well, and the numpy implementation perform very poor. Is there any problem? Can't I directly use them like nn.LayerNorm ?

## With torch

```
class Layer_norm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, eps=1e-6):
        super(Layer_norm, self).__init__()
        self.eps = eps
        
    def forward(self, x):
        mean = torch.mean(x, dim=(1, 2, 3), keepdim=True)
        var = torch.var(x, dim=(1, 2, 3), keepdim=True)
        std = torch.sqrt(var + self.eps)
        return (x - mean[:,None,None,None]) / std[:,None,None,None]
```

## With numpy

```
class Layer_norm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, eps=1e-5):
        super(Layer_norm, self).__init__()
        self.eps = eps
        
    def forward(self, x):
        mean = np.mean(x.cpu().numpy(), axis=(1,2,3))
        var = np.var(x.cpu().numpy(), axis=(1,2,3))
        div = np.sqrt(var+1e-5)
        out = (x.cpu().numpy()-mean[:,None,None,None])/div[:,None,None,None]
        return torch.from_numpy(out).float.cuda()
```